# How do I properly reference the GNU Readline Library in a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu, readline

I have the following line which I used to compile my current C project with the GNU Readline library in the terminal:

```
gcc code.c -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lreadline
```

How would I include this information in a Makefile so I could avoid typing this in every time I want to compile my project? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction But if you just want to avoid typing that all the time you can put it in a shell alias, or function or a script.

Answer (score 2):

You really should read the Makefile documentation and try to do this yourself. You wouldn't need to read far as that's pretty much Makefiles 101. Here is a very simple example to get you started. You can do much better than this.

```
my_program: code.c
    gcc code.c -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lreadline
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm just going through the documentation now. Thanks for the advice!